# What's the issue in validating the input data with regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, validation

I want to validate the text entered by user. The condition is that the text should contain alphanumeric  characters,hash(# symbol) and spaces in between words. For it I'm using following code but it's not accepting #(hash) symbol, returning FALSE everytime. Can someone please help me in this regard please so that it could return me true?

```
<?php
 $validate = alpha_num_symbol($field_value);

 function alpha_num_symbol($str) {

   return  (! preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.,!?]*$/",$str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try changing your regex character group to have the hash symbol? `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.,!?#]*$/`

Answer (score 0):

Using the pattern `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.,!?#]*$/` it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.,!?]*$/` has a character set `[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.,!?]` that matches zero or more times. There is no hash symbol in that character set, however there are other characters that you don't want to match according to your description. I would use this regex:

```
"/^[a-zA-Z0-9 #]*$/"
```